# Scala - How to concatenate List and Option values after joining two RDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, rdd

I have two RDDs that I want to join - `salesfromSource1: RDD[(String, List[Sale])]` and `filteredSales: RDD[(String, Sale)]`

Since I want to perform a left join I've tried the following:

```
val joinedSales: RDD[(String, (List[Sale], Option[Sale]))] = salesfromSource1.leftOuterJoin(filteredSales)
```

But how do I concatenate the values so that as a result I get `RDD[(String, List[InvocaCall])]`?

I expected to achieve this with `.mapValues(_._1 ::: _._2)`

However I'm getting a type mismatch compiler highlighting `(expected (List[Sale], Option[Sale]) => NotinferedU, actual: (Any, Any) => Any)`

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
.mapValues {
   case (x, None) => x
   case (x, Some(y)) => x :: y
}
```

or

```
.mapValues { x =>
  x._2.map(y => x._1 :: y).getOrElse(x._1)
}
```

Comment: I've tried both examples that you proposed but the compiler cannot resolve the  `::` symbol in `x :: y`. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I think that I found the answer.. Operators ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative.

Comment: @user10496094 In this case it should rather be `y :: x._1`, shouldn't it?